# CSS inline not working

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm having an issue where I cannot get an HTML element inline. I realise this reminiscent of issues that have occurred in the past, and that I can use methods such as `float` to get this to work, but I want to understand as well specifically why `inline` is not working.

Here is a JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/K27nT/2/. It's not 100% what the page looks like, but it shows my issue.

If you look towards the bottom, you'll see a link 'Remove Image'. This should be in line with `Logo` and `Select Image`, but it is not. I've set the CSS to display the elements `inline`, but no matter what I do, it does not work.

For the purposes of testing, I did change the display to `inline-block`, which despite working in the fiddle still fails in real life. I did also change the `<a>` element to `<span>`, just to see what happened, and that also failed. Thus I believe my issue is being caused previous to this element, but I do not know what could be causing it.

Can anyone please tell me why `inline` is not working in this case? Thanks.

As an FYI, here is am image of what the page actually looks like -
[image]

Comment: Why not just use `inline-block` that's what you should be using, as it is a block level element.. http://jsfiddle.net/PxJC5/

Comment: Ya every element by default is already display: inline; inline-block should be your solution, just be careful because inline-block is sensative to white space, if your magins are off off use float

Comment: I see that it has worked in your fiddle, but in my situation it is also not working (I did try before posting). Beside, regardless of `<a>` being a block level element, I don't require any of it's block level attributes, so in theory surly `inline` should work?

Comment: @DavidGard Yea - but 'select image' is in a `div` which is a `block` level element... Want me to post that as the solution..?

Comment: @JMcFee - All elements are not already `display: inline;` by default. Many are `block`, such as `<div>` and `<h1-5>`, and you also have many other types, such as `<table>`. Also please note that I'm trying to understand why it's not working, rather than just blindly going for a different solution.

Comment: @JoshC - I realise that, but the `<div>` that wraps `Select Image` is set to `display: inline;`. Everything in that 'line' is set to display `inline`, yet the `Remove Image` button wont...

Comment: The `div.loading-dd-options` inside the "Select Image"-`div` is still set to `display:block` and forces a line break.

Comment: @JoshC - I think I may have it. Even thought the `<div>` that wraps `Select Image` is `inline`, there is another `<div>` within it that is not. My understanding was that `inline` was based on the parent, but clearly the child is mucking it up in this case!

Comment: @JoshC - Yep, I'm with you now. Go for it on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply because there is still a `div` between the elements. In this case `.loading-dd-options`

You could solve this by setting it to be an `inline` element, as it is a `block` level element by default.

```
.loading-dd-options {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demonstrating that here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2JPGX/)

Alternatively, you could also set the elements to `inline-block`, and it will have the same effect.

[**jsFIddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PxJC5/)

Comment: Thanks for the talk through, I was unaware of this and thought that it would only have been a `block` level element within it's parent. I changed that `<div>` to a `<span>` and all is golden. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `div.loading-dd-options` inside the "Select Image"-`div` is still set to `display:block` and forces a line break. Every element with `display:block` starts in the next line and uses the full width of its parent, even if it is empty.

Comment: Thanks, together with @JoshC, this helped me sort the problem.